# Instances of Amazon AWS EC2 have no Internet / misconfiguration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I am able to connect to my Amazon AWS EC2 instances (Ubuntu) via SSH, but the Instances self can not connect to the Internet, what I noticed when doing

```
sudo apt-get update
```

that leads to a **timeout**. I have drawn a diagram of the current VPC configuration and hope that someone can tell me what is wrong:

[image]

I already controlled Inbound and Outbound rules but I cannot see something.
Can someone help me and tell what problem do I have? Is it maybe that the VPC CIDR has suffixmask 16 and the Subnet CIDR has suffixmask 20 or something like that?

By the way - I can not remember that I have changed something here.

```
VPC "vpc-cf8f91a4"
==================
My VPC-ID is vpc-cf8f91a4

The IPv4 CIDR is 172.31.0.0/16

Route table: rtb-f0da499a

Network ACL ID: acl-05e2486f

Internet Gateway "igw-a6b7aace"
===============================
igw-a6b7aace associated with vpc-cf8f91a4

Associated 2 Subnets
====================
subnet-faefd387 172.31.32.0/20 associated with route table rtb-f0da499a

subnet-febe7f94 172.31.16.0/20 associated with route table rtb-f0da499a

Route Table "rtb-f0da499a"

 Destination | Target | Status | Propagated 

 172.31.0.0/16 | local | active | No 

 0.0.0.0/0 | igw-a6b7aace | active | No
```

Comment: Take a look at this - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html. Possibly you're set up in a private subnet? That's what it sounds like. I think you'll need a NAT Gateway in that case.

Comment: Hi i think both subnets are public because they have a route to the internet gateway igw-a6b7aace - please have a look at my routing table which both subnets have been assigned to.

Comment: In general, **you should not modify the NACLs** unless you have a very specific use-case (eg creating a DMZ). **Only use Security Groups** to limit the traffic that can go in/out of an instance. Then, if you can connect to an instance via SSH, then the instance is correctly connected to the Internet. Any problems would be due to security groups or a firewall on the instance itself.

Comment: I can connect from outside to the instances via SSH but the instances self do not reach the Internet (sudo apt-get update is not working anymore). For the ACL I have added an rules after it didn't work but with no effect. You can see my current configuration in the uploaded diagram in my post. If you have any idea do not hesitate to post it :-) . I am running out of ideas

Comment: Can I assume that the inbound connections mean that you're connecting directly to the instance and not going through a VPN? If yes, then have you tried connecting out to another public host (ie, `wget https://www.google.com`). And if that fails, is it also a timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in one of the comments ACLs are an advanced feature and it's not recommended to use them unless you're familiar with the lower levels of the network stack and have a reason to use them, e.g. working in a highly secure environment, or need role separation such as network and development teams.

From the information you have provided the most likely issue is that you are blocking ephemeral port return traffic with your ACL. ACLs are stateless so you must allow return traffic.

For most tcp connections this means 1024-65535, if you add that as an inbound ACL rule and retest.

As a side note, you should not allow the internet to access your database, this is very bad practice. I would recommend you create another subnet that is private (no IGW route) and put the database in there, and do not give it a public IP address.

Comment: The default network acl is allowing anything - so i have allowed anything for inbound and outbound and now it works. THx